In MLflow, what is the recommended pattern to track provenance of artifacts across runs?
In MLflow, what is the recommended pattern to track provenance of artifacts across runs?
Having used Weights-&-Biases, I'm used to logging datasets, models, evaluation and inference results as artifacts across runs (as both, outputs and inputs). I'm not claiming that this is a perfect system, but I found it to be quite helpful. MLflow doesn't seem to work this way, if I understand the documentation correctly. There is mlflow.log_input, but it is limited to a single Dataset instance (no models or other input types), and it doesn't seem to matter whether that was created by another run. Am I missing something?
I use a local deployment with direct access to the file system. Tracking and using large artifacts works well, in principle.
